# How to change Random in to Sequence Order

Tags: android

I  am developing word scramble android app. I want to display the String of word in Sequence order but in below code it get random word from the dictionary. My question is how to change my code to get words from Dictionary in Sequence Order?

```
String[] dictionary=
{"One","Server","Terminate","Analyze","Finish","Start","Wonder","Slow"};

r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
newGame();

// shuffle algorithm
private String shuffleWord(String word){

    List<String>  letters = Arrays.asList(word.split(""));
    Collections.shuffle(letters);
    String Shuffled="";
    for (String letter : letters ){
        Shuffled += letter;

    }
    return Shuffled;
}

private void  newGame(){
    // get random word from dictionary
    currentWord= dictionary[r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];

    // show the shuffled word
    tv_word.setText(shuffleWord(currentWord));

    // clear the textfield
    et_guess.setText("");

    // switch buttons
    b_new.setEnabled(false);
    b_check.setEnabled(true);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you pick your word with a random position

```
 r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

using an integer random from 0 to ArrayOfWords lenght.

```
currentWord= dictionary[r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];
```

Why you dont try to make a counter instead?

```
int r = 0;
while (r<dictionary.length()) {
currentWord = dictionary[r];
r++; 
}
```

Or I don't understand your answer. But there is the pseudo of what I understand.

Comment: int r = 0;
currentWord = dictionary[r];
r++;     sir i tried.But it displays only one word.What i want to do to get all words one by one

Comment: Edited my answer, just put it in a loop.

Comment: int r = 0;
while (r<dictionary.length()) {
currentWord = dictionary[r];
r++; 
}    sir i used this code..it show error like "Method call expected"'.What i want to do